# How to make Windows 8 BCD show boot menu instead of booting directly into Windows 8?

Tags: windows-7, windows-8, boot, grub

I have Windows 8, Windows XP and Ubuntu on my computer. And I am completely disappointed of modern logic of Windows 8 BCD. Say, I need to boot into Windows XP. Steps I must perform:

1. Select "Windows 8" entry in GRUB menu.
2. Wait for Windows 8 to load.
3. Select "Load previous version of Windows" in logon screen
4. Reboot
5. Wait for GRUB menu to appear.
6. Repeat Step 1.
7. Load Windows XP.

Compare it with Windows 7 BCD logic:

1. Select "Windows 7" entry in GRUB menu.
2. Select "Load previous version of Windows" in boot screen.
3. Load Windows XP.

I leave the question whether this decision to the marketers. I also understand that Microsoft is not responsible for custom bootloaders (though they must keep in mind that somebody use them). I simply need to load WinXP like I did when used Win7. I know it is possible, but when I tried to replace Win8 loader with Win7 loader using EasyBCD, it did not make any difference (excluding that it wrote loader to the MBR, and I had to recover it).

UPD: I used [provided solution](https://superuser.com/a/621054/238619), but it seems to me that these settings are not kept after 2 restarts.

Should I use earlier version of EasyBCD, which is not aware of Win8? Or is there some hack to prevent Win8 to load every time I select it in boot menu? Please guide me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not possible with the Win8 Bootloader. But you can disable the the graphical Bootloader and switch back to the Win7 textbased version:

```
bcdedit /set {default} bootmenupolicy legacy
```

[image]

Now Windows 8 behaves like Windows 7.

[image]

Source:

http://www.askvg.com/how-to-disable-new-metro-boot-loader-and-bring-back-windows-vista-and-7-style-boot-loader-in-windows-8/

Comment: Please review my latest changes in question. Legacy boot meny disappears after some time :(

Comment: it works for me fine and stays as it is. Do you use other tools which modify the BCD?

Comment: No, I just play games there. I rewrote Win8 bootloader using EasyBCD, may be it is the reason. I don't think that Fallout 3 can change boot menu policy :)

Comment: this can be the cause.

Comment: I rewrote MBR from installation media then restored GRUB. Now it works :)